# How to dispose a sprite in Libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

After searching, I found out Sprite is a subclass of TextureRegion in Libgdx. 
So how to dispose a Sprite object?

```
public void create() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    sprite = new Sprite(new Texture("pizza.jpg"));


}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();

    batch.end();

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    sprite.getTexture().dispose();
```

Is this the correct way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the Sprite class itself doesn't have a dispose method, so that's how you would dispose of the Sprite's texture.

However, a better way overall would be to use the [`AssetManager` class](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets) to load the texture and dispose of it. Doing so allows you to manage all your textures in one place (thus being able to dispose of them all at once when your program exits, if needed).

Here's an example from a game I'm currently working on:

```
public class Controller extends Game {
    @Override
    public void create () {
        // Some loading stuff ...

        // Initialize the asset manager
        // TODO: Make a snazzy loading bar
        assetManager = new AssetManager();
        assetManager.load(ATLAS_NAME, TextureAtlas.class);
        assetManager.finishLoading();

        // Other loading stuff...
    }

    // Other methods snipped for space reasons...

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        // I dispose of things not managed by the asset manager...

        // Dispose of any other resources
        assetManager.dispose();
    }

/**
     * Convenience method to safely load textures. If the texture isn't found, a blank one is created and the error is logged.
     * @param imageName The name of the image that is being looked up.
     * @return
     */
    public TextureRegionDrawable getManagedTexture(String imageName) {
        try {
            return new TextureRegionDrawable(assetManager.get(ATLAS_NAME, TextureAtlas.class).findRegion(imageName));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Gdx.app.error(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Couldn't get managed texture.", e);
            return getEmptyTexture();
        }
    }
    public TextureRegionDrawable getEmptyTexture() {
        return new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(new Pixmap(1,1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888))));
    }
}
```

Admittedly I created a funky method which wraps asset manager so that I always get a texture back (even if it's blank), but the normal use of asset manager is as simple as this:

```
Texture tex = assetManager.get("my/texture/name.png", Texture.class);
```

It works with other classes too like Atlases and Skins.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give a specific example of doing so for someone who is new to Libgdx like me?

Comment: Thank you. i think so, so basically AssetManager is great managing lots of image files. I will look more into it.